# WordPress pagination does not go to last page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am trying to use a custom `WP_Query` for my loop in order to limit the number of posts that I show per page. However, the pagination functions doesn't seem to respect this limit that I set. Here is my code:

```
$current_page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$author_post_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'author_name'    => $curauth->user_nicename,
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $current_page,
    'orderby'        => 'modified',
    'no_found_rows'  => true,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => '1'
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $author_post_args );

$temp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query   = NULL;
$wp_query   = $loop;

if($loop->have_posts()):
    while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="post-list">
            <?php 
            $title = the_title("", "", false);
            ?>
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a></h2>
            <time>Last Updated — <?php the_modified_date('F j, Y'); ?></time>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        </div>
<?php
    endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();

previous_posts_link('<i class="fas fa-backward"></i> Newer Posts');
next_posts_link('Older Posts <i class="fas fa-forward"></i>', $loop->max_num_pages);

$wp_query = NULL;
$wp_query = $temp_query;
```

I searched for a solution on the website and found [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops). The solution seems to work for the OP but not for me.

In my case, the posts per page are limited to 5. However, the number of pages is still stuck at 3. I can't go to page 4 and get a `Not Found` error. There are total 26 posts by the author. Therefore, I should be able to go to page 6.

The number of pages is still determined by the functions based on the value specified under `Settings > Reading > Blog pages show at most` in WordPress dashboard which is set to 10.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that WordPress is working off of the assumption that you're still expecting 10 posts per page because your query is effectively a standalone query in the middle of a page. Are you just trying to limit the number of posts per page on this particular post type? Or is there something else you're trying to do?

You can achieve this in a far cleaner way by using [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

```
function tweak_posts_per_page( $query ) {
    if( !is_admin() && $query->is_author() && $query->is_main_query() ) :
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'modified' );
        return;
    endif;
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'tweak_posts_per_page');
```

Add this code in your functions.php file or similar; if needed you can add additional conditionals to the IF statement to handle when this adjustment will be applied. You should find your pagination will work after that.

pre_get_posts is used to adjust the query that WordPress will run *before it runs the query*

Additionally, you can remove the query from your code altogether - just keep the loop in there to loop through what is now your *adjusted* main query.

edit: added the additional 'is_author' conditional statement, and added the 'orderby' adjustment

Comment: Thanks efreeman. :)

I don't undertsand this part "you're still expecting 10 posts per page because your query is effectively a standalone query in the middle of a page". The number of results shown on the page is equal to the value I set for `posts_per_page` in my custom query.

However, the total number of pages is limited to 3 as if WordPress ignores my value when counting the total number of pages.

Comment: Yes, I want to lmit the number of posts per page to 5 for author pages. The code I provided in the question still does that. However, it does not go beyond page 3.

Comment: I mean WordPress is still expecting 10 posts per page because it has already run the main query (which is behaving as expected, following the posts per page limit set in the admin) - your query is not directly affecting the *main* query. 3 pages makes sense with 26 posts / 10 posts per page, 10 on pg1, 10 on pg2, 6 on pg3 - I will edit the conditional statement you'll need to tackle author pages shortly!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation efreeman. :) I just have one more question. In my custom query, I specify that I want the posts to be ordered based on their last modification date. The posts that are echoed on the page are indeed ordered based on their last modified date. My question is, why is the value I set for `orderby` and `posts_per_page` reflected in the output but not used for calculating the total number of pages. Thanks. :)

Comment: pre_get_posts allows you to adjust more than just the posts per page values :) it's a very useful tool! I'll edit the answer to show you how to adjust the sort order using pre_get_posts as well :)

Comment: I am sorry as my question wasn't very clear. :)

I was saying that running the code from the question using a custom `WP_Query`, I can still get 5 posts per page which are ordered based on the modification date as specified in `$author_post_args`. This means that WordPress fetches the posts based on the parameters I specify in my custom query. As you said, my query is run after WordPress has already run its main query but it still kept my custom parameters in mind. ___ 1/2

Comment: Is there a specific reason why WordPress cannot get the correct number of pages as well based on the parameters specified in custom `WP_Query`?
Thanks. :)      ____2/2.

Comment: Yes, you call this "$wp_query = $temp_query;" presumably to reinstate the original query - this is unnecessary as wp_reset_postdata effectively does the same thing, it returns the query variable back to its original state and as you're doing so before the pagination functions, it's only giving you links up to page 3 - you might be able to use the pagination functions *before* calling the wp_reset_postdata function and have it display the correct page links, but the pre_get_posts method is a much cleaner solution - hope that makes sense!